# Putting SharedPrefs Editor in Utility Class?

Tags: java, android, android-sharedpreferences

Is it a good idea/practice to put static shared preferences editor in a utility class so I can call it whenever needed? The method in the utility class would look like this:

```
public static SharedPreferences.Editor editor (Context context){
    final SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    return sharedPrefs.edit();
}
```

and use it like this in different classes:

```
Utility.editor(mContext).putBoolean(categoryId, true);
Utility.editor(mContext).apply();
```

Comment: It is good as well. and you can use like
    `Utility.editor(mContext).putBoolean(categoryId, true).apply();`

Comment: Ok but it is costly solution in that case if you want to store multiple keys.

Answer (score 4):

At least I would't say it's a *bad* idea.

But here is an even better idea: abstract away the Android specific details and create a clean, readable interface for storage access that fits your **domain**.

e.g:

```
   interface UserSettings {
      void setAutoReloadEnabled(boolean enabled);
      boolean isAutoReloadEnabled();
     ...
   }
```

and then implement it using `SharedPreferences`

```
 class SharedPreferencesUserSettings implements UserSettings {

   final SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;

   public SharedPreferencesUserSettings(Context ctx) {
      sharedPrefs = ...;
   }

   @Override void setAutoReloadEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        sharedPrefs.editor().putBoolean("...", enabled).commit();
   }

   ...

 }
```

This gives you more readable code and you can actually provide a stub/mock implementation in your tests! If the API of SharedPreferences should change (or when you want to move from using `commit` to `apply` or vice-versa, or changing the Tags you used for the preferences) you only have to change it in one File, not everywhere in your code.
But there is more: if you should later decide that `SharedPreferences` were actually a bad choice, you can switch the implementation to use e.g. a . SQLite Database or ObjectBox instead. Again, without changing the rest of the code.

Needless to say that this might be overkill (aka over-engineering) in certain situations, but in bigger projects this pays out pretty fast.

Answer (score 1):

Its not necessarily a bad idea and it will clean up the code. But it will slow your app down.
Not by a noticeable amount but nonetheless - if time is an issue in your project do not do this. If not, then go ahead.